# Designing a ribbon button in OfficeJs using manifest

Tags: excel, angularjs, office-js, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Is it possible to add spacing in between ribbon buttons? I cant seem to design the ribbon in anyway and am constricted to OfficeJs standards.

I would like to design my ribbon, I am currently developing using AngularJS and have created my own custom ribbon but still cant design or add spacing on my buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place any controls for your custom ribbon on the task pane. But ribbon customizations in Office applications (made by web add-ins) allow the following control types:

- Simple buttons - trigger specific actions.
- Menus - simple menu dropdown with buttons that trigger actions.

There is no property for configuring spaces and etc. Read more about possible ribbon customizations in the [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) article.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.